# Execution order of Javascript promises when different promise chains attached

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I wanted to check the portability of a `promise` object by creating an `promise` and passing it around and let others attach `then`s to it. The output is far from what I expected and I don't understand how it executed.

```js
const wait = time => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(res, time);
  });
};

const promise = wait(5000)
  .then(() => console.log('1'));

promise
  .then(() => console.log('2'))
  .then(() => console.log('3'));

promise
  .then(() => console.log('4'))
  .then(() => console.log('5'));
```

**output:**

```
1
2
4
3
5
```

I debug the code and here is what I observed. calling `wait(5000)` invokes constructor of `Promise` that calls `setTimeout` API by passing `res` callback and  `Promise` object is returned back. then it starts registering all the `then`s from 1 to 5 in the same order. After 5 seconds it calls `res` from `Promise` object which invokes the promise chains.

In my mind, `then` API adds all the `callbacks` to an array or something like that, from 1 to 5 and once `res` is called it starts calling `callbacks` from the array one by one (FIFO) which should produces logs `1 2 3 4 5` not `1 2 4 3 5`.

How is this not executed in order they are being registered to the main `promise`?

Comment: Shouldn't you be assigning to the promise each time to build the chain? `const promise = wait(5000) .then(() => console.log('1')); promise = promise.then(() => console.log('2'))  .then(() => console.log('3')); promise= promise
  .then(() => console.log('4'))
  .then(() => console.log('5')); promise;`

Comment: @Eggon It's not about how It's should have been done. It's about understanding why it does it the way it does.

Comment: (2, 3) and (4, 5) belongs to two concurrent promise chains, so they will be resolved in the order of 2 and 4, then 3 and 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, when you do this:

```
promise.then(...).then(...)
```

That attaches one `.then()` handler to `promise` and the second `.then()` is attached to a new promise that the first `.then()` returns.

So, when `promise` resolves, the first `.then()` is scheduled to fire on the next tick of the event loop.  Then, only when the first `.then()` finishes, it schedules the second `.then()` to fire on the next tick of the event loop (it does not run on this tick of the event loop).

When you do this:

```
promise
  .then(() => console.log('2'))
  .then(() => console.log('3'));

promise
  .then(() => console.log('4'))
  .then(() => console.log('5'));
```

And, then when `promise` resolves, `then(2)` and `then(4)` which are the only two `.then()` handlers in this piece of code directly attached to `promise` are scheduled to run on the next tick of the event loop.  Upon that next tick, first `then(2)` runs and then `then(4)` runs.  Since they were both attached to the same promise, they run in a FIFO manner, the first one to be attached runs first. When `then(2)` runs, it schedules `then(3)` to run on the next tick of the event loop and when `then(4)` runs, it schedules `then(5)` to run on the next tick of the event loop.

So, after both `then(2)` and `then(4)` have run, upon the next tick of the event loop, you will see `then(3)` and `then(5)` run and that explains the sequencing you see in the console of:

```
1
2
4
3
5
```

---

I presume you're not surprised that `then(1)` runs first so I didn't add that to the explanation.

> How is this not executed in order they are being registered to the main promise?

The three `.then()` handlers attached directly to `promise` do run in the order they were attached.  What is apparently confusing you is that the chained `.then()` handlers are not attached directly to `promise`, but to new promises that `promise.then()` returns.

`.then()` returns a new promise because it may not resolve immediately.  If the callback inside of `.then()` itself returns a promise, then the promise that `.then()` returns does not immediately resolved.  It has to wait until the promise that the `.then()` callback returned also resolves.

> In my mind, then API adds all the callbacks to an array or something like that, from 1 to 5 and once res is called it starts calling callbacks from the array one by one (FIFO) which should produces logs 1 2 3 4 5 not 1 2 4 3 5.

Well: 1, 2 and 4 are indeed added to the same array of `.then()` handler callbacks for the `promise` object.  But, as explained above, 3 and 5 are on separate promises that were created by the `.then()` they are chained to.  So, 1, 2 and 4 are executed FIFO.  But 3 and 5 are delayed to a subsequent tick of the event loop.

Comment: Wait. Here the only `asynchronous` call is `setTimeout` and we are passing `res` method to it. So yeah, after 5 seconds `res` will end up in the `event loop` to be executed. BUT nothing after that is `asynchronous`. So what the hell those `then()` callbacks are doing in the `event loop`? How did `Promise` added them to the event loop in the first place? Does this mean `Promises` are not just Javascript implementation but a browser's native functionality?

Comment: @s1n7ax - EVERY `.then()` handler is always executed asynchronously on a future tick of the event loop after its parent promise was resolved.  This is part of the specification promises.  This is done so that the flow of code is identical whether a promise is resolved immediately or some time in the future.  The Javascript that is currently executing finishes and returns back to the system and then, only after that, are `.then()` handlers run that are attached to promises that were just resolved (essentially on the next tick of the event loop).  That's how promises are designed.

Comment: @s1n7ax - Promises actually have their own high priority execution path so they generally cut in front of other events waiting in the event queue (this is probably also done for performance reasons for promise chains).

Comment: @s1n7ax - Simple example:  `Promise.resolve(1).then(x => console.log(x)); console.log(2);` will show as `2`, then `1` because `.then()` is scheduled for the next tick of the event loop, but `console.log(2)` is run in this tick of the event loop.

Comment: @s1n7ax - Did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes. last code certainly did. Do you know how it is sends callback function to the event loop?