# Node JS Promises Behavior

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm working with promises & i can't understand it's behavior in node js.

```
function m1(txt) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(txt + ' - done');
      resolve()
    }, 1000);
  });
}

var foo = m1('a');

foo.then(() =>  m1('b').then(() => console.log('do something immediately after b')));

foo.then(() => m1('c'));
```

Expected output, also getting it in chrome console.

```
a - done
b - done
do something immediately after b
c - done
```

But i'm getting following output in Node JS.

```
a - done
b - done
c - done
do something immediately after b
```

Kindly help i can't understand why this happening and what i do to get my expected output.

Comment: The then callbacks just add things to the "to-do list", I don't think it's guaranteed by the language what order those things will be done in. Note in Chrome you're probably running that line by line, whereas Node runs through all of the lines immediately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execution order of Javascript promises when different promise chains attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60781048/execution-order-of-javascript-promises-when-different-promise-chains-attached)

Comment: @jonrsharpe No i didn't run this code line by line explicity on chrome, u can check by just copy & paste provided code in chrome. and ok i agree with you, there is no guarantee but can you suggest any way so i can do it, thnx for respsonse

Comment: @shajji Why do you even want to change this behaviour? If you absolutely need to do something *immediately* after the `console.log`, your only choice is to place it in the code right after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To acheive my expected output, I did the following changes

```
function m1(txt) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(txt + ' - done');
      resolve()
    }, 1000);
  });
}

var foo = m1('a');

foo = foo.then(() =>  m1('b').then(() => console.log('do something immediately after b')));

foo = foo.then(() => m1('c'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time a promise resolves, **all (first level) `.then()` attached to it are scheduled to execute on the next tick of the event loop**. So in your case:

```js
foo.then(() => m1('b').then(() => console.log('do something immediately after b')));
foo.then(() => m1('c'));
```

Once `foo` has resolved, we get the first log:

```
a - done
```

The callbacks of `foo` will be scheduled to execute in the next tick of the event loop:

```
| Next tick |
|:---------:|
|  then(b)  |
|  then(c)  |
```

So once executed the tick, we get the following log:

```
a - done
b - done
c - done
```

Remember `then(b)` had the log callback. So during the execution, the callback is added to the next event loop tick. So the next tick will be:

```
| Next tick |
|:---------:|
| then(log) |
```

So once executed the second tick, we get your final log:

```
a - done
b - done
c - done
do something immediately after b
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello please check the node version. Before v11 u will get:

```
a - done
b - done
c - done
do something immediately after b
```

with v11 and above it will be:

```
a - done
b - done
do something immediately after b
c - done
```

as there were changes to make it follow the browser behavior. Here's a helpful article about that
https://blog.insiderattack.net/new-changes-to-timers-and-microtasks-from-node-v11-0-0-and-above-68d112743eb3

Comment: i didn't check your answer, cause i already achieve my expected output & also post it as answer, +1 for respond :)